# How to assign a value to a field in different class?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object, methods

In this program, I have 2 classes Application and Customer. I want to initialize Standard Fare with some value which should be entered by the user. Standard Fare field is in Customer class.
I did this, but it is not showing the desired result. When Calculate function is called The Value of Standard fare is becoming zero.

When I initialize the value of STANDARD_FARE in Customer class itself, then the program is working as desired.
How can I input the value given by the user to STANDARD_FARE?

Also methods like GetAge(), GetPassNo() in Application class is not returning the value of the same.

```
 class Application
  {
    private static int Nop ;
    private static double TotalFare=0;
    Customer cust= new Customer(); 

    static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Application obj = new Application();                      
        Console.Write("Enter the STANDARD RATE of the tour ");
        obj.cust.StandardFare = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        a:
        Console.Clear();                                             
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of passengers");
        Nop = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                       

        Application[] app = new Application[Nop];                 

        if (Nop <= 0)                                               
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number of passengers");
            Console.ReadKey();                                     
            goto a;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Nop; i++)
        {
            app[i] = new Application();                           
            app[i].GetInformationFromCust();         
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < Nop; j++)
        {

           app[j].cust.Display();                                  

       }                                             
     }

    public int GetInformationFromCust()
    {      
         b:
        Console.Clear();                                     
        int slen = 0;                                   

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the title of the passenger");
        cust.Customer_Title = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nEnter passenger's First name :");
        cust.Customer_FName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nEnter passenger's Last name :");
        cust.Customer_LName = Console.ReadLine();
        slen = cust.Customer_FName.Length + cust.Customer_LName.Length;    
         if (slen < 5 || slen > 15)                                       
          {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nName should be between 5 to 15 characters, Please try again ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            goto b;
          }

        c:
        long x = 0, len = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nEnter the passport number of the passenger ");
        cust.CustomerPassNo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        x = cust.CustomerPassNo;               

         while (x > 0)
          {
            x = x / 10;                    
            ++len;
          }
        if (len != 8)                    
          {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nInvalid passport number, passport should be of 8 digits ");
            goto c;
          }

        d:
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nEnter the age of the passenger :");
        cust.Customer_Age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          if (cust.Customer_Age < 0)                                         
          {
             Console.WriteLine("\r\nInvalid age, please enter a valid age ");
             goto d;
          } 
        cust.CalculatePrice();                                          
        return 0;
    }

    public int GetAge()
    {
        return cust.Customer_Age;
    }

    public double GetAirFare()
    {
        return cust.CustomerTicket ;
    }

    public long GetPassportNo()
    {
        return cust.CustomerPassNo;
    }

    public string GetTitle()
    {
        return cust.Customer_Title;
    }
 }
```

```
class Customer 
  {
    const double K_DISCOUNT = 0.10;                            
    const double S_DISCOUNT = 0.20;

    private double STANDARD_FARE;
    private string CustomerName { get; set; }
    private int CustomerAge;
    private string CustomerFName;
    private string CustomerLName;
    private long CustomerPassport;
    private double CustomerPrice; 
    private string CustomerTitle;
    private double KidDiscount;
    private double SeniorDiscount;

    public Customer()                                         
    {
        this.KidDiscount = K_DISCOUNT;
        this.SeniorDiscount = S_DISCOUNT;
    }

    public double StandardFare
    {
        get { return STANDARD_FARE; }
        set { STANDARD_FARE = value; }
    }

    public int Customer_Age
    {
        get { return CustomerAge; }
        set { CustomerAge = value; }
    }

    public string Customer_Title
    {
        get { return CustomerTitle; }
        set { CustomerTitle = value; }
    }

    public string Customer_FName
    {
        get { return CustomerFName; }
        set { CustomerFName = value; }
    }

    public string Customer_LName
    {
        get { return CustomerLName; }
        set { CustomerLName = value; }
    }

    public long CustomerPassNo
    {
        get { return CustomerPassport; }
        set { CustomerPassport = value; }
    }

    public double CustomerTicket
    {
        get { return CustomerPrice; }
        set { CustomerPrice = value; }
    }


    public int CalculatePrice()
    {
        if (CustomerAge < 3)
        {
            CustomerPrice = 0;
        }
        else if (CustomerAge >= 3 && CustomerAge < 18)
        {
            CustomerPrice = STANDARD_FARE - (STANDARD_FARE * KidDiscount);
        }
        else if (CustomerAge > 65)
        {
            CustomerPrice = STANDARD_FARE - (STANDARD_FARE * SeniorDiscount);
        }
        else
        {
            CustomerPrice = STANDARD_FARE;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
      //some code here
    }
}
```

[image: OUtput]

Comment: I highly recommend that you not use `goto`.  Just use a `do-while` loop instead.

Comment: You alread set the standard fare here: `obj.cust.StandardFare = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`. You just **need to make sure** that you then also use the **same** Application and Customer object on which you did set the value from the user input. If you look into _other_ Customer objects, then of course you will not find the value the user did input...

Comment: Why do you create a new `Application` object in `GetInformationFromCust`?

Comment: i am using array of objects in order to take data of multiple passengers.

Comment: how can i use that object to initialize STANDARD FARE.

Comment: @juharr ignore that object i was trying something in that method

Comment: Does `Application` refer to a software application (which I think is what people will first assume) or is it a business object (e.g. an application for a passport or a job application)?

Comment: it refers to a software application .

Comment: Then why do you need so many instances of them? Seems like there should be only one.

Comment: Actually, it is an assessment problem given to me, in which it is clearly mentioned that I have to create 2 classes named Application and Customer and they also mentioned all the fields and methods to be used.

Comment: i have to use arrays to  enter the data of user, so i used array of object to enter the data of the passengers so that i can refer to that data by using specific indexes.

Comment: HOW CAN I INITIALIZE STANDARD_FARE by taking the value of it from the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are populating your array `app` with instances of `Application` that still have the default `STANDARD_FARE` value (which is 0.0), because *you have never set it on those instances*. You **only** set it on the `obj.cust` instance, **which you never again use**. Because `STANDARD_FARE` is an instance variable, changes to it have no affect on other (or future) instances.

You have the same problem in reverse with all the `Application.Get*` functions; they are getting properties of an object (`obj.cust`) that has never had any properties set, other than `StandardFare`/`STANDARD_FARE`.

The most obvious fix is to **do away with `obj` and `obj.cust` entirely** - they have no use other than to be confusing - and **make `STANDARD_FARE` a static variable** (and its setter `StandardFare` a static property).

---

BTW, your naming conventions are terrible and inconsistent; if I were your grader I'd dock you points for using unclear variable names(`app`, `nop`), and for using ALL_CAPS for non-constants (`STANDARD_FARE`). I'd also object to using a private auto-backed property (`CustomerName`, which is also never used) instead of simply a private variable, for *not* using auto-backed properties elsewhere (`StandardFare` as an explicitly-coded public getter and setter for `STANDARD_FARE`, etc.), and for copying constant values into non-settable instance variables (`K_DISCOUNT` to `KidDiscount`; just use the constant directly, or at least make `KidDiscount` static and add some non-private access to it). As others have mentioned, you of course should not be using `goto` in place of loops. I'll also mention the error-prone and inefficient checking the length of the passport number by repeated division instead of simply checking whether it's less than 99999999 (in theory, passport numbers might start with a zero, which would look like less than 8 digits after parsing, but you could also make sure it's greater than 10000000 if you want).

Comment: Thank you, I made STANDARD_FARE and its property static, and it's all fine now.
I also removed obj object of class Application as you mentioned. 

Since it was not my final code there were some problems with naming that i didn't corrected.
 
1) STANDARD_FARE is all caps because before I had the value of it defined already. 
   But now I wanted the value of STANDARD_FARE to be taken from the user
     so I didn't change it now but I would have later, 

2) app = object for class Application, 
   Nop = No. of Passengers.

Comment: 3) That CustomerName thing I corrected now, it was all because I was doing 
    something else before in my code. 

4) In my Question, it was mentioned that I should use constant values and also 
     Fields named KidDiscound and SeniorDiscount.
     Hence, I did that unprofessional stuff there to satisfy the problem requirement

5)  Ok, I will replace all the goto's used with some other logic. and that passport 
    number checking logic too.

Thank you for your help. Kudos